# Solidity, Visualizing [object object] when checking wallet address with hardhat, ethers.js

Tags: solidity, ethers.js, hardhat

I'm having this issue when testing this lines of code:

```js
it("Subscribes multiple deployers", async function () {
              const additionalEntrances = 3
              const startingIndex = 0
              const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
              for (let i = startingIndex; i < startingIndex + additionalEntrances; i++) {
                MarketOrder = MarketOrder.connect(accounts[i])
                await MarketOrder.Deposit(ArraySL[i], { value: ArrayValue[i] })
                console.log(`Account: ${accounts[i].toString()}  Value: ${ArrayValue[i]} SL: ${ArraySL[i]}`)
              }
            })
```

And this is how it shows in the console

```
Account: [object Object]  Value: 5000000000000000000 SL: 1200
Account: [object Object]  Value: 10000000000000000000 SL: 1502
Account: [object Object]  Value: 20000000000000000000 SL: 1960
```

How can I visualize wallet address properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
```

Each element of the `accounts` array is an instance of the `ethers.js` [Wallet](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet) object.

And Javascript casts any object (that doesn't override the `toString()` method) to string as `[object Object]`.

If you want to print an address of the wallet, you can use its [address property](https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/signer/#Wallet--properties):

```
console.log(`Account: ${accounts[i].address}`)
```